# JavaScript regex that checks if nested parentheses are balanced

Tags: javascript, regex

Title kinda says it all. This is what I have right now:

```js
const str = "(((111)00)(01)(02)))))";
const rgx = /\([^()]*\)/g;
str.match(rgx).forEach(function(m) {
  document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', m + '<br>');
});
```

Mine will get all nested parentheses if they are directly inside of the outer parentheses. However it will not work if I nest parentheses within another nested parentheses (Inception style).

Right now for the string `"(((111)00)(01)(02))"` it returns `(111), (01), (02)` in my example. I would like it to return `(111), ((111)00), (01), (02)`.

Really my final goal is to check for balance and return `true` or `false` depending on the result.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Pedantry: The movie Inception's title means to create an idea in someone's mind through their dreams so they thought they came up with the idea themselves - it has nothing to do with recursion or reentrancy.

Comment: Maybe someone is creating parenthesis inside of parenthesis without his knowledge which is why he wants regex to catch the parenthetical inception

Comment: since you loop results anyway, i would use two simpler regexps and concat them before filtering or foreaching

Comment: Why not increment an integer each time you find a `(` and  decrement it whenever you find `)`? If your integer ends at 0 your parentheses are balanced.